# Chat application stops after 2 messages exchange

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming

I am writing a simple chat application in python and it works fine for just 2 messages and after that its stop responding...any idea about it?

ServerClass.py

```
from socket import *
import time

class ServerClass:
    serverSocket = None
    serverPort = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.serverPort=20000
        self.serverSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        #self.serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.serverSocket.bind(("",self.serverPort))
        self.serverSocket.listen(10)

    def StartServer(self):
        while 1:
            connectionSocket,clientAddress=self.serverSocket.accept()
            message=connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            print message.split(':')[0]+": "+message
            modifiedMessage = raw_input("To send: ")
            connectionSocket.send(modifiedMessage)
    #connectionSocket.close()
```

Client Class.py

```
from socket import *

class ClientClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.serverIP="localhost"
        self.serverPort=20000
        self.clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        self.your_name="Nadeem Ahmed"

    def Connect(self):
        self.clientSocket.connect((self.serverIP,self.serverPort)) 

    def SendMessage(self,Message):
        self.clientSocket.send(Message) 
        modifiedMessage=self.clientSocket.recv(1024)
        print modifiedMessage

    def Leave(self):
        self.clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: There were minor errors in your code layout for SO which I fixed. Please check that your indentation is still ok.

Comment: Try to set TCP_NODELAY option, so TCP buffer can be pushed on every send, also use sendall instead of send

Comment: Another bug is around your accept, it should be outside of while loop and have it call another method - which does the client handling